# Set checked checkbox based on database

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a system where user can choose their selection and once they saved and return back to the page, the checkbox will be checked according to the saved value in the database and user can make changes/update their selection. Below is my code:

```
<?php $conn=new PDO( "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT bs_services FROM business_service WHERE bs_center = :email AND bs_package = 'Essential'");
$sql->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
$rows = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>

<button type="button" class="accordion"><b>Engine</b>
</button>
<div class="panel-accordion" style="max-height: auto;">
    <div class="row">

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-1" name="service[]" value="Up to 4.5 L standard oil change" <?php if($row[ 'bs_services']=="Up to 4.5 L standard oil change" ) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-1">Up to 4.5 L standard oil change</label>
        </li>

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-2" name="service[]" value="Up to 6.0 L standard oil change" <?php if($row[ 'bs_services']=="Up to 6.0 L standard oil change" ) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-2">Up to 6.0 L standard oil change</label>
        </li>

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-3" name="service[]" value="Up to 6.0 L high quality change" <?php if($row[ 'bs_services']=="Up to 6.0 L high quality change" ) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-3">Up to 6.0 L high quality change</label>
        </li>

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-4" name="service[]" value="Replace oil filter up to $20" <?php if($row[ 'bs_services']=="Replace oil filter up to $20" ) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-4">Replace oil filter up to $20</label>
        </li>

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-5" name="service[]" value="Replace oil filter up to $40" <?php if($row[ 'bs_services']=="Replace oil filter up to $40" ) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-5">Replace oil filter up to $40</label>
        </li>

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-6" name="service[]" value="Carry out engine diagnotistic scan" <?php if($row[ 'bs_services']=="Carry out engine diagnotistic scan" ) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-6">Carry out engine diagnotistic scan</label>
        </li>

    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

However, all it does is to display the accordion and it's child repeatedly.

The data are saved like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttwpH.png)

Comment: a how's  your data saved?

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you saved in the table `business_service` 1 check per row, so right now, your code is printing all the checkboxes as many times as items selected, you should store the checkboxes in an array, and then check the array

```
<?php 
$conn=new PDO( "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", 

$username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); $sql 
$conn->prepare("SELECT bs_services FROM business_service WHERE bs_center = :email AND bs_package = 'Essential'"); $sql->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR); $sql->execute(); $rows = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $checks[$row[ 'bs_services']] = true;
}
?>
<button type="button" class="accordion"><b>Engine</b>
</button>
<div class="panel-accordion" style="max-height: auto;">
    <div class="row">

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-1" name="service[]" value="Up to 4.5 L standard oil change" <?php if(isset($checks["Up to 4.5 L standard oil change"])) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-1">Up to 4.5 L standard oil change</label>
        </li>

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-2" name="service[]" value="Up to 6.0 L standard oil change" <?php if(isset($checks["Up to 6.0 L standard oil change"])) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-2">Up to 6.0 L standard oil change</label>
        </li>

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-3" name="service[]" value="Up to 6.0 L high quality change" <?php if(isset($checks["Up to 6.0 L high quality change"])) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-3">Up to 6.0 L high quality change</label>
        </li>

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-4" name="service[]" value="Replace oil filter up to $20" <?php if(isset($checks["Replace oil filter up to $20"])) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-4">Replace oil filter up to $20</label>
        </li>

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-5" name="service[]" value="Replace oil filter up to $40" <?php if(isset($checks["Replace oil filter up to $40"])) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-5">Replace oil filter up to $40</label>
        </li>

        <li class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="amenity-6" name="service[]" value="Carry out engine diagnotistic scan" <?php if(isset($checks["Carry out engine diagnotistic scan"])) echo "checked"; ?>>
            <label for="amenity-6">Carry out engine diagnotistic scan</label>
        </li>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `foreach`; instead, use the `while` loop.

Change the

```
$rows = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
```

to:

```
while ($rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Comment: It still display the accordion repeatedly. Where should i place the while loop? Because there is multiple of accordion. More than 10. In my code above, i just put one accordion.

Comment: @fredrick Replace the two lines indicated, with the `while`  statement mentioned. Also, ensure that the values returned from your SQL query is consistent with the value you are evaluating against (i.e. no trailing or preceding spaces etc.)

Comment: Yes i did replace that one. But say the $rows return 10 results, the accordion will be displayed as 10 and only the last accordion have the checkbox checked. How can i avoid it displays repeatedly?